# How to update only one column value in database using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table with columns `username`, `password`. Data can be updated by admin for the table.

Now I want to add a new column named `IsAgree` (as a flag), it need to set when user logs in for the first time. But while setting data, it should not affect other column data, I will only send usename and Isagree flag as an object.

```
flgDetail = { usename:"vis" Isallowed:True }

[Route("api/TermsAndCondition/setflag")]
public IHttpActionResult post(FlagDetails FlagDetail)
{
    var user = _context.table.Where(s => s.UserName == flagDetail.UserName);
}
```

Should I use post or put?

How can I update only one column?

And it should not affect other columns.

Comment: Is `_context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` set to true?

Comment: where it has to set?

Comment: If you have not changed it it should be set to `true`. It is usually managed inside context, for example in the constructor. But you can check it where you want. `bool isEanbled = _context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled;`. If `AutoDetectChanges` is enabled, EF will update only changed properties

Comment: Did you try to change the IsAgree of user variable and call SaveChanges? Since you got it from the context with your query, setting the IsAgree will only affect this field. Try this and post if you get any problems

Answer (score 1):

you can use either `post` or `put`.It's not a problem.You can update it as shown below.

```
[Route("api/TermsAndCondition/setflag")]
public IHttpActionResult post(FlagDetails flagDetail)
{
    var user = _context.table.Where(s => s.UserName == flagDetail.UserName);
    user.IsAgree =flagDetail.Isallowed;
   _context.SaveChanges()
}
```